# condition not satisfied still the php is running

Tags: php, database, wordpress, for-loop, switch-statement

Hello I have an array and I'm looping through it using `for loop` and inside for loop, there is `switch cases` I don't know why my code is running even if switch condition is not fulfilled

Here is my code:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($fees_type_arr);$j++){
    $month = "N/A";
    switch ($fees_type_arr[$j]) {
        case 'adm':
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $admission_fees,
                    'fees_type' => 'adm'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "trn":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $transport_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'trn'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "ann":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $annual_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'ann'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "rec":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $recreation_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'rec'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is my array

```
$fees_type_arr = array("adm","ttn","trn","ann","rec");
```

tid is the primary key and I'm getting an error Duplicate entry for primary key which is due to the code inside 1st `case` i.e `case "adm"` is running multiple times

Comment: What is $tid? Please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do $j+1 in your code it overrides the value of $j and again set it back to 1. So each time your loop will call the first case which is "adm". You need to store the real value of $j and assign it back in the end. Use this code.

```
for($j=0;$j<count($fees_type_arr);$j++){
    $month = "N/A";
    $oldj = $j;
    switch ($fees_type_arr[$j]) {
        case 'adm':
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $admission_fees,
                    'fees_type' => 'adm'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "trn":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $transport_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'trn'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "ann":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $annual_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'ann'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;

        case "rec":
            $sql_record_data = array(
                    'tid' => $tid.$j+1,
                    'slip_no' => $slip_no,
                    'date_time' => $current_date_time,
                    'uid' => $uid,
                    'month' => $month,
                    'amount' => $recreation_chg,
                    'fees_type' => 'rec'
            );
            if($wpdb->insert($record_table, $sql_record_data)){
                $ok = 1;
            }
            else{
                $ok = 0;
                throw new Exception($wpdb->print_error());
            }
        break;
    }
    $j = $oldj;
}
```

It will reassign the real value to $j and will work perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable $tid seems like a string. So even if $j is an incremental integer, $tid.$j+1 will result as 1.

You can change that to $tid.($j+1) (adding brackets).

Example :

```
<?php 
$tid = 'test';
$j = 10;
echo $tid.$j+1;
// returns 1
?>
```

After change :

```
<?php 
$tid = 'test';
$j = 10;
echo $tid.($j+1);
// returns 'test11'
?>
```

Just on  a lighter note, it seems like there is a lot of repetitive code in the example you have submitted, you can move it to a function or more dynamic looping to avoid code duplication.